# UIViewController UIButton can't touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have two `UIViewController`, A & B

```
[A addSubView: B.view];
```

it's ok.

but i got an question, i can't get the B's `UIButton` Touch Event after `[A addSubView: B.view]` 
why?

is anyone can help me
thank you~

Here's my some code :

A View:

```
 CellAction_ViewController *cellActionViewController = [[CellAction_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CellAction_ViewController" bundle:nil];

 [cell.contentView addSubview:cellActionViewController.view];
 [cellActionViewController.button_like addTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(Likes_Button:)
                                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

B View:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

// bala bala ...
   [_button_like setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

}

Comment: try to set `clipToBounds` to `YES` for your `UIButton` and check

Comment: try `[UIButton bringSubViewToFront];`

Comment: Dheeraj Singh   sorry, i put my code~

Comment: @arthankamal i set it to yes lo...

Comment: @Sam i try you says: 
    [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:cellActionViewController.button_like];
    [cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
 but it's not get touch event..

Comment: where have u defined Likes_Button: method.

Comment: @DheerajSingh i defined in A View : 
- (IBAction)Likes_Button:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will Work.... 
Instead of
    [A.view addSubview:B.view];

Use this

```
[A addChildViewController:B];
[B didMoveToParentViewController:A];
```

Because your are adding A **ViewController** subview.It should be A **ViewController**'s views sub view.

Comment: hello, i used you says~ :  [cell.contentView addSubview:cellActionViewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:cellActionViewController];
 [cellActionViewController.button_like addTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(Likes_Button:)
                                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    
    [cellActionViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

it's can't to touch.